# No managedObjectContext defined in my AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to test my core data scheme. However, it seems I am unable to create the context because it says `No visible @interface for 'MyAppDelegate' declares the selector 'managedObjectContext'`.

In online tutorials this method seems to be auto-generated when we create the app. However, in my case it doesn't exist.

This is MyAppDelegate:

Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"


@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

How should I fix this in Xcode 5 with iOS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way for you is to create a `Master-Detail Application` with Xcode 5 and don't forget to check `Use Core Data` :

[image]

With that, you will have an `AppDelegate.h` and an `AppDelegate.m` configured with a `managedObjectContext`.

You will have a project configured correctly with Core Data and a .xcdatamodeld to use easily your SQLite database.