# Saving a variable to a CoreData entity in code - Objective-C / XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

So, I have a very simple app going in order to learn Obj-C, where a user generates a score and then I want to post that score to some sort of "user-leaderboard".

What I have working
1. Generate score 
2. Move to a leaderboard view controller and pass score to the new view controller 
3. Add the score to a temporary array.

Now, I've created a Scores entity in CoreData, but I've never used CoreData before so I'm a bit confused as to how to use it.

[image: I've added the "Scores" entity to my CoreData file here]

Ideally, what I'd like to do is instead of saving the `scoreToBeAddedString` to the array, add it to the `Scores` entity.

I tried to use this call, but I got a bunch of errors.

```
CoreDataAppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
   NSManagedObject *newScore;
   newScore = [NSEntityDescription
       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Scores"
       inManagedObjectContext:context];
   [newScore setValue: _scoreToBeAddedAsString forKey:@"score"];
   NSError *error;
   [context save:&error];
```

Errors: 
1. `Use of undeclared identifier: 'CoreDataAppDelegate`
2. `Use of undeclared identifier: 'appDelegate`

Here is my `LeaderboardViewController.m` file.

```
#import "LeaderboardViewController.h"

@interface LeaderboardViewController ()

@end

@implementation LeaderboardViewController

{
    NSMutableArray *scores;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Convert the scoreToBeAdded int to a string 

    NSNumber *anumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:_scoreToBeAdded];

    NSString *scoreToAddAsString = [anumber stringValue];

    //[scores addObject:scoreToAddAsString]; //This is where I was adding the score to the array, but I want to get rid of this solution, so I can persist the data. 

    //TODO: Add the scoreToAddAsString to the "Scores" entity in CoreData. 

    NSLog(@"Leaderboard loaded w new score to add %i", _scoreToBeAdded);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [scores count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [scores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` in your `LeaderboardViewController.h` file.

Add `#import "CoreDataAppDelegate.h"` in your `LeaderboardViewController.m` file.

Comment: Thanks, Vivek. Have done that now. Bunch of other errors, I screenshotted here. http://i.imgur.com/QodmvXp.png?1 Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Vivek. It says that CoreDataAppDelegate.h cannot be founded. Could it be called something else in my setup?

Comment: Here is a screenshot so you can see my project too: http://i.imgur.com/b7SwglT.png?1

Comment: Appears that you havent declared that variable in your code

Comment: 1. I renamed CoreDataAppDelegate.h to JPAppDelegate.h given thats what my appdelegate file is named.
2. Ah, you are right. How should I declare the variable in the code?

Comment: Can you send the snapshot of your entire viewDidLoad Code?

Comment: 1) Make Following changes:
Replace and uncomment :
    //CoreDataAppDelegate *JPAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

with:
JPAppDelegate *JPAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


2) Where you declared  scoreToBeAdded variable?
According to your code it must be declared in your LeaderboardViewController.h file.

Comment: Thanks for point 1. Regarding point 2. The scoreToBeAdded variable comes in via another view controller, and I convert it to a string inside viewDidLoad here -> `NSNumber *anumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:_scoreToBeAdded];` and `NSString *scoreToAddAsString = [anumber stringValue];`

Comment: and yes its declared inside 'LeaderboardViewController.h' here: 
`@property (nonatomic, assign) int scoreToBeAdded;`

Comment: Ok.Are you still getting errors for scoreToBeAdded?

Comment: There is only one error left `No visible @interface for 'JPAppDelegate' declares the selector 'managedObjectContext`

Comment: Vivek, I think I may have found the problem. When I created the app, I probably didn't check "Use core data". http://stackoverflow.com/a/19432410/2656127

Comment: Just created a new project, then copied all the app delegate data over - fixed. Thanks! :)

Comment: Ya.I was about to say that.It seems like you missed other needed set up for core data  in appDelegate file.Happy Coding..!! :)