# How to store table value into core data entity in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity, row

I am having data Like This:

```
Appliance        Average Power Rating (Watts)   Alternate  Power Rating (Watts)
Fridge/Refrigerator       120                                       55 
Microwave                 1000                                     1000 
Mixie                     700                                       200 
Roti Maker                30                                        300
```

I want to store this data into my entity in CoreData. Just I have created an entity called `EY_Appliance` with attributes `applianceId`, `applianceName`, `watts` and `amountPerWatts`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving a variable to a CoreData entity in code - Objective-C / XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470631/saving-a-variable-to-a-coredata-entity-in-code-objective-c-xcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write code in this way. This will insert new Object for your entity with following attributes. You can edit it as per your requirement.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *powerDesc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EY_Appliance" inManagedObjectContext:context];


[powerDesc setValue:self.applianceId.text forKey:@"applianceId"];
[powerDesc setValue:self.applianceName.text forKey:@"applianceName"];
[powerDesc setValue:self.watts.text forKey:@"watts"];
[powerDesc setValue:self.amountPerWatts.text forKey:@"amountPerWatts"];

// Save the context
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Saving Failed!, Error and its Desc %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Where i have to write this Code....Bcoz it shows error in Firstline.It shows No known Class for managedObjectContext....

Comment: @Raghunath Dude you need to learn basics first..I am busy right now, will update a detailed code in sometime.

Comment: @Raghunath Where is the code for creating coredata file?

Comment: I have added entity with Attributes.After That i clicked file-new-coreData-NsManagedObjectSubClass.Finally am having EY_Appliances.h,EY_Appliances.m,EY_Appliances+CoreDataProperties.h,EY_Appliances+CoreDataProperties.m.....

Answer (score 0):

For that you can create and add the core data object as follows

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EY_Appliance" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[object setValue:self.applianceIdValue forKey:@"applianceId"];
[object setValue:self.applianceNameValue forKey:@"applianceName"];
[object setValue:self.wattsValue forKey:@"watts"];
[object setValue:self.amountPerWattsValue forKey:@"amountPerWatts"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
NSLog(@"Saving Failed with error %@", error);
}
```

Comment: It stores Only Last Data.Just am storing array values in Set value using Loop.How to array values in SetValue...